# AngularJS: Populating One Array from Another (Creating Pages)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Hey Guys,

I am trying to split my responses from my RSS feed reader up into pages. I'm doing this by populating a feedList array with RSS Items, and taking 2 items at a time to display and placing them in a displayList array connected to an ng-repeat. When you click next page it will update the displayList array with 2 new items from the feedArray.

I got a simplified version running with an array of names http://jsfiddle.net/halfasleep/ZJFke/4/

When I tried to implement it with the feed reader code, it doesn't populate the displayList array before trying to display it, when you hit "Next Page" it will drop some items into the displayList array and start to display it (though for some reason only moving 1 item at a time instead of 2). Any help would be appreciated!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WDL8U/

Html

```
<html ng-app="FeedReader">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reader Trial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FeedReader.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="blogCtrl">
    There are {{feedList.length}} entries.
    <ul class="blogPosts" ng-class="listClass" ng-init="populate();">
        <li ng-repeat="list in displayList"><h2><a ng-click="publish(list.content);">{{list.title}}</a></h2><p>{{list.contentSnippet}}</p><span> - {{list.author}}</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="blogPosts fullWidth" style="height: 500px; overflow: scroll;" ng-hide="noCont" ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <a ng-click="prev()" ng-hide="hideP">Previous Page</a>
        <a ng-click="next()" ng-hide="hideN">Next Page</a>
    </div>
    <script src="./feedReader2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var feedList = [];
var displayList = [];
var app = angular.module('FeedReader',['ngResource']);

app.factory('feedLoader',['$resource', function($resource){
    var googleAPI = $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load',{},{ 
        collect: { 
            method: 'JSONP', 
            params: { 
                v: '1.0', 
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            } 
        } 
    });
    return googleAPI;
}]);

app.service('createFeedList',['feedLoader', function(feedLoader){
    this.get = function(){
            var feed = {
                feedName: 'Slashdot',
                feedURL: 'http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot'
            };

            feedLoader.collect({
                q: feed.feedURL, 
                num: 10
            },{},function(result){
                var feed = result.responseData.feed.entries;
                for(i = 0; i < feed.length; i++){
                    feedList.push(feed[i]);
                }
            });
        return feedList;
    }
}]);

app.controller('blogCtrl',['$scope', '$sce', 'createFeedList', function($scope, $sce, createFeedList){
    $scope.feedList = createFeedList.get();

    // Page Code


    $scope.hideP = true;

    var begin = 0;
    var end = 2;
    $scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];

    $scope.next = function(){
        if(end <= $scope.feedList.length - 2){
            begin += 2;
            end += 2;
            $scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];
            $scope.hideP = false;
        }
        if(end == $scope.feedList.length-1) {
            $scope.hideN = true;   
        }
    }

    $scope.prev = function(){
        if(end == 3){
            $scope.hideP = true;
        }
        if(end >= 1) {
            begin -= 2;
            end -= 2;
            $scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];
            $scope.hideN = false;
        }
    }


    // Display Content Code
    $scope.noCont = true;
    $scope.listClass = 'fullWidth';

    $scope.publish = function(cont) {
        $scope.noCont = false;
        $scope.htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(cont);
        $scope.listClass = 'halfWidth';
    }
}]);
```

Comment: get() needs to return a promise. Right now `$scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];` is running before the feed is fetched; needs to wait till promise is resolved. There is also at least one more error (`var end = 2;` should be `var end = 1;`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what promises were originally, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Also thank you for sorting out my page iteration issue, I just couldn't see it even when it was so obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a promise and then populate $scope.feedList when the data is ready. Then you can perform actions on the other $scope variables as well. Give this a try:

```
var feedList = [];
var displayList = [];

var app = angular.module('FeedReader',['ngResource']);

app.factory('feedLoader',['$resource', function($resource){
    var googleAPI = $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load',{},{ 
        collect: { 
            method: 'JSONP', 
            params: { 
                v: '1.0', 
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            } 
        } 
    });
    return googleAPI;
}]);

app.service('createFeedList',['feedLoader', '$q', function(feedLoader, $q){
    this.get = function(){
            var feed = {
                feedName: 'Slashdot',
                feedURL: 'http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot'
            };
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            feedLoader.collect({
                q: feed.feedURL, 
                num: 10
            },{},function(result){
                var feed = result.responseData.feed.entries;
                for(i = 0; i < feed.length; i++){
                    feedList.push(feed[i]);
                }
                deferred.resolve(feedList);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);

app.controller('blogCtrl',['$scope', '$sce', 'createFeedList', function($scope, $sce, createFeedList){
    //$scope.feedList = createFeedList.get();
    createFeedList.get().then(function(data) {
        $scope.feedList = data;

        $scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];

    $scope.next = function(){
        if(end <= $scope.feedList.length - 2){
            begin += 2;
            end += 2;
            $scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];
            $scope.hideP = false;
        }
        if(end == $scope.feedList.length-1) {
            $scope.hideN = true;   
        }
    }

    $scope.prev = function(){
        if(end == 3){
            $scope.hideP = true;
        }
        if(end >= 1) {
            begin -= 2;
            end -= 2;
            $scope.displayList = [$scope.feedList[begin],$scope.feedList[end]];
            $scope.hideN = false;
        }
    }
    });
    // Page Code


    $scope.hideP = true;

    var begin = 0;
    var end = 2;



    // Display Content Code
    $scope.noCont = true;
    $scope.listClass = 'fullWidth';

    $scope.publish = function(cont) {
        $scope.noCont = false;
        $scope.htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(cont);
        $scope.listClass = 'halfWidth';
    }
}]);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for being slow to get back to you on this. That worked perfectly, I wasn't really sure what promises were when I heard about them, this really helped me understand. Thank you!